# Spring - How to inherit the properties alone

Tags: java, spring, inheritance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="ParentBean" class="com.sample.spring.Parent"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="message" value="Hello World!" />
</bean>

<bean id="ChildBean" class="com.sample.spring.Child"
    parent="ParentBean">
    <property name="message1" value="Good Morning"></property>
</bean>

<bean class="com.sample.spring.PostHelloWorld" />
```

Here, I am trying to inherit the property "message" from ParentBean to ChildBean, but at the runtime it throws the exception as below,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'ChildBean' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is      org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValidationException: 
Couldn't find an init method named 'init' on bean with name 'ChildBean'
```

From the above i can understand that the ChildBean is also inheriting the initialization and destroy methods as well.

**Question,**

Is there anyway i can make it only inherit the properties alone?

Comment: @Mekswoll thanks for your response, however, I would like to know why ChildBean looking for `init`  method when i not defined it in ChildBean bean

Comment: No you can't... Both bean definitions are merged, a workaround is to create another bean definition (without those methods and without a class and mark it abstract) and use that as parent for both concrete beans.